# PyOpenCl Kernel in Loop Crashes GPU

Tags: python-3.x, pyopencl

I am writing a neighbor look up routine that is brute force using pypopencl. Later on it will fit into my smoothed particle hydro code. Brute force certainly is not efficient but its simple and its a starting point. I have been testing my look up kernel and I find that when I run it in a loop it crashes. I don't get any error messages in python but the screen flickers off, then comes back on with a note that the graphics drivers failed but have been recovered. The odd thing is that if the number of particles that are searched over are small (~1000 or less) its does just fine. If I increase the count (~10k) it crashes. I tried adding in barriers and wait commands, and a finish command, to no avail. I checked to see if I have an array overrun but I cannot find it. I am including the relevant code and apologize upfront for the size of it but wanted to give it out everything so people can look at it. I am hoping some one can run this and recreate the error, or tell me where I am going wrong. My setup is python 3.5 using spyder and installed pyopencl 2016.1.

Thanks,

Seth

**First The main file**

```
import numpy as np
import gpuParameters as gpuParameters
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as ar
from BruteForceSearch import BruteForceSearch
import time as time

dim = 3  # dimensions of the problem
n = 15000  # number of particles
nbs = 50   # number of neighbors
x = np.random.rand(n)  # randomly choose some x
y = np.random.rand(n)  # randomly choose some y
z = np.random.rand(n)  # randomly choose some z
h = np.ones(n)  # smoothing parameter for the b spline

# setup gpu context
gpu = gpuParameters.gpuParameters()
# neighbor list
nlist = -1*np.ones(n*nbs, dtype=np.int32)

# data to gpu
xg = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, x)  # x pos on gpu
yg = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, y)  # y pos on gpu
zg = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, z)  # z pos on gpu
hg = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, h)  # h pos on gpu
num_p = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, np.array(n, dtype=np.int32))  # num of particles
nb = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, np.array(nbs, dtype=np.int32))  # num of neighbors
nlst = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, nlist)  # neighbor list on gpu
dg = ar.to_device(gpu.queue, np.array(dim, dtype=np.int32))  # dimension on gpu
out = ar.zeros(gpu.queue, n, np.float64)  # debug parameter

# call the Brute force neighbor search and h parameter set class
srch = BruteForceSearch(gpu)  # instatiate
s = time.time()  # timer start
for ii in range(100):
    # set a marker I really didn't think this would be necessary
    mark = cl.enqueue_marker(gpu.queue)  # set a marker for kernel complete
    srch.search.search(gpu.queue, x.shape, None,
                       num_p.data, nb.data, dg.data, xg.data, yg.data, zg.data,
                       hg.data, nlst.data, out.data)  # run the kernel
    cl.Event.wait(mark)  # wait for complete run of kernel before next iteration
    # gpu.queue.finish()
    print('iteration: ', ii)  # print iteration time to show me its running
e = time.time()  # end the timer
cs = time.time()  # clock the time it takes to return the array
nlist = nlst.get()
ce = time.time()
# output the times
print('time to calculate: ', e-s)
print('time to copy back: ', ce - cs)
```

**GPU Context Class**

```
import pyopencl as cl

class gpuParameters:
    def __init__(self, dType  = []):
        #will setup the proper context based on given device preference
        #if no device perference given will default to first value
        if dType == []:
            pltfrms = cl.get_platforms()[0]
            devices = pltfrms.get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU)
            context = cl.Context(devices) #create a device context
        print(context)
        print(devices)
        self.cntxt = context#keep this context in motion
        self.queue = cl.CommandQueue(self.cntxt) #create a command que for this context
        self.mF = cl.mem_flags
```

**Neighbor Loop up**

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
import gpu_sph_assistance_functions as gsaf

class BruteForceSearch:
    def __init__(self, gpu):
        # instantiation of the search routine primarilly for pre compiling of
        #  the function
        self.gpu = gpu  # save the gpu context

        # setup and compile the search
        self.bruteSearch()

def bruteSearch(self):
    W = gsaf.gpu_sph_kernel()
    self.search = cl.Program(
        self.gpu.cntxt,
        W + '''__kernel void search(__global int *nP, __global int *nN,
                                __global int *dim,
                            __global double *x, __global double *y,
                            __global double *z, __global double *h,
                            __global int *nlist, __global double *out)
        {
            // indices
            int gid = get_global_id(0);  // current particle
            int idv = 0;  // unrolled array id
            int count = 0;  // count
            int dm = *dim;  // problem dimension
            int itr = 0;  // start iteration
            int mxitr = 25;  // max number of iterations
            // calculate variables
            double dms = 1.0/(*dim);  // 1 over dimension for pow
            double xi = x[gid];  // current x position
            double yi = y[gid];  // current y position
            double zi = z[gid];  // current z position
            double dx = 0;  // difference in x
            double dy = 0;  // difference in y
            double dz = 0; // difference in z
            double r = 0;  // radius
            double hg = h[gid];  // smoothing parametre
            double Wsum = 0; // sum of weights
            double W = 0;  // current weight
            double dwdx = 0;  // derivative of weight in x direction
            double dwdy = 0;  // derivative of weight in y direction
            double dwdz = 0;  // derivative of weight in z direction
            double dwdr = 0;  // derivative of weight in r direction
            double V = 0;  // Volume of particle
            double hn = 0;  // holding value for comparison
            double err = 10;  // error
            double tol = 1e-7; // tolerance
            double diff = 0;  // difference

            // first clean the array of neighbors
            for (int ii = 0; ii < *nN; ii++)  // length of num of neighbors
            {
                idv = *nN*gid + ii;  // unrolled index
                nlist[idv] = -1; // this is a trigger for excluding values
            }
            // Next calculate the h parameter
           while (err > tol)
            {
                Wsum = 0; // clean summation
                for (int jj = 0; jj < *nP; jj++)  // loop over all particles
                {
                    dx = xi - x[jj];
                    dy = yi - y[jj];
                    dz = zi - z[jj];
                    // spline for weights
                    quintic_spline(dm, hg, dx, dy, dz, &W,
                                   &dwdx, &dwdy, &dwdz, &dwdr);
                    Wsum += W;  // add to store
                 }
                V = 1.0/Wsum;  /// volume
                hn = pow(V, dms);  // new h parameter
                diff = hn - hg;  // difference
                err = fabs(diff);  // error
                out[gid] = err;  // store error for debug
                hg = hn; // reset h
                itr ++;  // update iter
                if (itr > mxitr)  // break out
                {   break; }
            }
           h[gid] = hg;  // store h

            /*  // get all neighbors in vicinity of particle not
             // currently assessed
            for(int ii = 0; ii < *nP; ii++)
            {
                dx = xi - x[ii];
                dy = yi - y[ii];
                dz = zi - z[ii];
                r = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
                if (r < 3.25*hg & count < *nN)
                {
                    idv = *nN*gid + count;
                    nlist[idv] = ii;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            */

    }
        ''').build()
```

**The Spline function for weighting**

```
W = '''void quintic_spline(
        int dim, double h, double dx, double dy, double dz, double *W,
        double *dWdx, double *dWdy, double *dWdz, double *dWdrO)
        {
            double pi = 3.141592654; // pi
            double m3q = 0; // prefix values
            double m2q = 0; // prefix values
            double m1q = 0; // prefix values
            double T1 = 0; // prefix values
            double T2 = 0; // prefix values
            double T3 = 0; // prefix values
            double D1 = 0; // prefix values
            double D2 = 0; // prefix values
            double D3 = 0; // prefix values
            double Ch = 0; // normalizing parameter for kernel
            double C = 0; // normalizing prior to h
            double r = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
            double q = r/h; // normalized radius
            double dqdr = 1.0/h; // intermediate derivative
            double dWdq = 0; // intermediate derivative
            double dWdr = 0; // intermediate derivative
            double drdx = dx/r; // intermediate derivative
            double drdy = dy/r; // intermediate derivative
            double drdz = dz/r; // intermediate derivative
            if (dim == 1)
            {
                C = 1.0/120.0;
            }
            else if (dim == 2)
            {
                C = 7.0/(pi*478.0);
            }
            else if (dim == 3)
            {
                C = 1.0/(120.0*pi);
            }
            Ch = C/pow(h, dim);
            if (r <= 0)
            {
                drdx = 0.0;
                drdy = 0.0;
                drdz = 0.0;
            }

            // local prefix constants
            m1q = 1.0 - q;
            m2q = 2.0 - q;
            m3q = 3.0 - q;

            // smoothing parameter constants
            T1 = Ch*pow(m3q, 5);
            T2 = -6.0*Ch*pow(m2q, 5);
            T3 = 15.0*Ch*pow(m1q, 5);

            //derivative of spline coefficients
            D1 = -5.0*Ch*pow(m3q,4);
            D2 = 30.0*Ch*pow(m2q,4);
            D3 = -75.0*Ch*pow(m1q,4);

            // W calculation
            if (q < 1.0)
            {
                *W = T1  + T2 + T3;
                dWdq = D1 + D2 + D3;
            }
            else if (q >= 1.0 && q < 2.0)
            {
                *W = T1  + T2;
                dWdq = D1 + D2;
            }
            else if (q >= 2.0 && q < 3.0)
            {
                *W = T1;
                dWdq = D1;
            }
            else
            {
                *W = 0.0;
                dWdq = 0.0;
            }
            dWdr = dWdq*dqdr;
            // assign the derivatives
            *dWdx = dWdr*drdx;
            *dWdy =  dWdr*drdy;
            *dWdz =  dWdr*drdz;
            *dWdrO = dWdr;
        }'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code on a Intel i7-4790K CPU with AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing. It does not crash at n=150000 (I only run one iteration). The only odd thing I discovered while quickly looking into the code, was that the kernel is reading and writing in the array h. This should not be a problem, but still I usually try to avoid this.

Comment: I will go back and try to do this as two separate arrays one for input one for output. Might fix the problem. Thank you for looking at it.